# Read comma separated csv file with fields containing commas using fread in r

Tags: r, csv, data.table, fread

I have a csv file separated by comma. However, there are fields containing commas like company names "Apple, Inc" and the fields will be separated into two columns, which leads to the following error using fread.

"Stopped early on line 5. Expected 26 fields but found 27."

Any suggestions on how to appropriately load this file?

Example rows are as follows. It seems that there are some fields with comma without quotes. But they have whitespace following the comma inside the field.

```
100,Microsoft,azure.com
300,IBM,ibm.com
500,Google,google.com
100,Amazon, Inc,amazon.com
400,"SAP, Inc",sap.com
```

Comment: If the fields aren't protected by quotation marks of some kind you're kind of screwed unless there is some other structure you can exploit ... can you post a brief/reproducible example (e.g. as a code-formatted text block)?  How big is the file (this will determine the practicality of various hacks/workarounds) ?

Comment: Thanks Ben! The comma inside a field is followed by a whitespace. The file is not very large. I think I may need to change the column separator to semi-colon.

Comment: If there are fields without quotes with comma (`Amazon, Inc`) how will you know that they are supposed to be one field? If you want to adjust them based on whitespace you need to read them using `readLines` and do some text processing.

Comment: If changing the separator is an option that would be (by far) the easiest option ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Using the test file created in the Note at the end and assuming that the file has no semicolons (use some other character if it does) read in the lines, replace the first and last comma with semicolon and then read it as a semicolon separated file.

```
L <- readLines("firms.csv")
read.table(text = sub(",(.*),", ";\\1;", L), sep = ";")
##    V1          V2         V3
## 1 100   Microsoft  azure.com
## 2 300         IBM    ibm.com
## 3 500      Google google.com
## 4 100 Amazon, Inc amazon.com
## 5 400    SAP, Inc    sap.com
```

**2)** Another approach is to use gsub to replace every comma followed by space with semicolon followed by space and then use chartr to replace every comma with semicolon and every semicolon with comma and then read it in
as a semicolon separated file.

```
L <- readLines("firms.csv")
read.table(text = chartr(",;", ";,", gsub(", ", "; ", L)), sep = ";")
##    V1          V2         V3
## 1 100   Microsoft  azure.com
## 2 300         IBM    ibm.com
## 3 500      Google google.com
## 4 100 Amazon, Inc amazon.com
## 5 400    SAP, Inc    sap.com
```

**3)** Another possibility if there are not too many such rows is to locate them and then put quotes around the offending fields in a text editor.  Then it can be read in normally.

```
which(count.fields("firms.csv", sep = ",") != 3)
## [1] 4
```

### Note

```
Lines <- '100,Microsoft,azure.com
300,IBM,ibm.com
500,Google,google.com
100,Amazon, Inc,amazon.com
400,"SAP, Inc",sap.com
'
cat(Lines, file = "firms.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me. Can you provide a reproducible example?

```r
library(data.table)

# Create example and write out
df_out <- data.frame("X" = c("A", "B", "C"),
                     "Y"= c("a,A", "b,B", "C"))

write.csv(df_out, file = "df.csv", row.names = F)

# Read in CSV with fread
df_in <- fread("./df.csv")
df_in
```

```
   X   Y
1: A a,A
2: B b,B
3: C   C
```

Comment: Thanks AdamK! There are some fields without quotes but with comma inside. This should be the issue for the error message.

Comment: Yes.Warning message:
In fread("~/Desktop/fread_sample.txt", header = F) :
  Stopped early on line 4. Expected 3 fields but found 4. Consider fill=TRUE and comment.char=. First discarded non-empty line: <<100, Amazon, Inc, amazon.com>>